# "Missing column" error message for valid json in Azure's Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

For a test case, I uploaded manually a test json file to my Data Lake Gen2. When debugging my data flow in the Data Factory, the Data preview throws the following error:

at Source 'testJson': Missing column 'id

I checked the validity of the json and everything seems to be fine. The file is in UTF-8 format.

This is my test file:

> [{"id":"590cf","updated_at":"1592228694942"}
> ,{"id":"590d3","updated_at":"1592228694942"}
> ,{"id":"590d4","updated_at":"1592228694942"}
> ,{"id":"590d5","updated_at":"1592228694942"}
> ,{"id":"590d6","updated_at":"1592228694942"}
> ,{"id":"590d7","updated_at":"1592228694942"}
> ,{"id":"590d8","updated_at":"1592228694942"}]

Any idea? Could it be a bug in ADF?

According to the comment I also processed the data further into CSV. I can't see any problem.

[image]

These are some screenshots of my pipeline:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you use the copy activity from your JSON to a CSV file with auto column mapping turned on, what are the resultant columns?  It may be that as you have an array of objects in your file, you need to reference the columns slightly differently

Comment: Hi @iamdave. I added the result of a copy pipeline, where I am storing the data into a CSV file. This pipeline is working with success.

Comment: Would need to see some screenshots of your Data Flow to be able to debug any further

Comment: Hi @Matzka, do you mean the data preview has the error in data flow and it works well in copy active?  In Data Flow, do you import the schema? I tried and didn't have any error.

Comment: @Leon: I am getting the error when trying to fetch the data with "Data Preview", but I am also getting this error when running the whole pipeline in debug mode or running the whole pipeline in general. The additional test pipeline with the csv as a suggestion by iamdave works fine.

Comment: @iamdave: I just added some screenshots. From my point of view it looks like a bug in ADF.

Comment: @Matzka Can you please check the inspect? Please try delete the '[]' from the json file.

Comment: @Leon: I added a screenshot of the inspect part.

Comment: @Matzka Thanks, it very strange···and It make me confused.

Comment: @Leon: Yes, indeed, I really can't see any mistake in setting up the source of the data flow. That is why I think it could be just a bug in ADF. I tested it with txt-files in json, with json files, I changed the namings of the columns, etc...

Comment: @Matzka It may be, but there is no error on my side and we can't repeat it. I use EDGE browser and only set the Allow schema drift.

Comment: I also created a new data set for the source, but leading to the same error.

Comment: @Matzka well, let's consider it as the bug, we're sadly that we have no solution for it. Let me post it as the answer?